# How to send ActiveMQ VirtualTopic in node js?

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

## How to send ActiveMQ VirtualTopic in node js ?

Am using stompit library for send and receive queue.
This will working properly.

I need to send virtual topic, How to implement in node ?

```
 ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.VirtualTopic 

 ActiveMQConnectionFactory allow to create producer and topic in java
```

But, there is no option like that in node js.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5tqE.png

If I produce from Java then
Topic: Lenovo.*  (marked red color in screen shot)
then automatically created ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.Lenovo.*
(Marked green color in screen shot)

Not create ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic when produce from node

Answer (score 1):

Virtual destinations are just named endpoints like any other.  To send to one the client would send to a destination like '/topic/VirtualTopic.Orders' and then consume from the queue '/queue/Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders' and that is about it.  See the [documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) for the Virtual Destinations feature in ActiveMQ to understand how the naming works.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Now am edited my question and attached image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5tqE.png

Please look and clarify

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense really so hard to provide better answer